# Finding the highest frequency of an array and all elements which have that frequency

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, frequency

I'm asked to find the highest frequency from an array of elements and all elements with said frequency. My code seem to work just fine but it seems to have a mistake somewhere when i submit it. Can anyone help me find the error?

**Format Input:**
The first line contains an integer T stating the number of test cases. For each test case, the first line contains a single integer N which indicate the number of element in the array. The next line contains N integers Xi (1≤i≤N) which indicate *i*th element in the array.

**Format Output:**
Consists of T lines where each line has the format “Case #X: Y ”, where X is the test case number starting at 1 and Y is the highest frequency. Next line contains all elements which have that frequency sorted in ascending order.

**Constraints:**
1 ≤ T ≤ 20 | 2 ≤ N ≤ 20.000 | 1 ≤ Xi ≤ 2 × 10^5

**Sample Input:**

```
3
8
1 1 2 2 3 4 5 5
8
5 5 4 3 2 2 1 1 
4
1 1 1 3
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Case #1: 2
1 2 5
Case #2: 2
1 2 5
Case #3: 3
1
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int T, N[20];

    scanf("%d", &T); getchar();
    
    int A[T][20000];
    
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i<T; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &N[i]); getchar();
        for (int j = 0; j<N[i]; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &A[i][j]); getchar();
        }
        
        int X = 0;
        
        for (int j = 0; j<N[i]; j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k<N[i]; k++) {
                if (A[i][k]<A[i][j]) {
                    X = A[i][j];
                    A[i][j] = A[i][k];
                    A[i][k] = X;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    int f[20000];
    
    for (int i = 0; i<T; i++) {
        int c = 0, mc = 0;
        
        for (int j = 0; j<N[i]; j++) {
            c = 1;
            if(A[i][j] != -1) {
                for (int k = j+1; k<N[i]; k++) {
                    if (A[i][j] == A[i][k]) {
                        c++;
                        A[i][k] = -1;
                        
                    }   
                }
                
                f[j]=c;
            }   
            if (c>mc) {
                    mc = c;
                }
        }
        printf("Case #%d: %d\n", i+1, mc);
        
        for (int j = 0; j<N[i]; j++) {
            if (A[i][j] != -1) {
                if (f[j] == mc) {
                    printf ("%d", A[i][j]);
                    if (j<N[i]-1) {
                        printf(" ");
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
        printf("\n");
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**
So I made another code where instead of inputting all arrays at once and outputting everything at once, this code outputs the frequency and elements after i input the first arrays of numbers. But it seems like the code still have problems and i can't find where... P.s I'm pretty new to this, so i apologise for the lack of efficiency of my codes.

**NEW CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int T, N;

    scanf("%d", &T); getchar();
    
    int A[20000];
    
    for (int i = 0; i<T; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &N); getchar();
        for (int j = 0; j<N; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &A[j]); getchar();
        }
        
        int X;
        
        for (int j = 0; j<N; j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k<N; k++) {
                if (A[k]<A[j]) {
                    X = A[j];
                    A[j] = A[k];
                    A[k] = X;
                }
            }
        }
        
        int f[N], c = 0, mc = 0;
        
        for (int j = 0; j<N; j++) {
            c = 1;
            if(A[j] != -1) {
                for (int k = j+1; k<N; k++) {
                    if (A[j] == A[k]) {
                        c++;
                        A[k] = -1;
                    }   
                }
                f[j]=c;
                if (c>mc) {
                        mc = c;
                }
            }   
        }
        printf("Case #%d: %d\n", i+1, mc);
        
        for (int j = 0; j<N; j++) {
            if (A[j] != -1) {
                if (f[j] == mc) {
                    printf ("%d", A[j]);
                    if (j<N-1) {
                        printf(" ");
                    }
                }   
            }   
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Why did you tag it c++? Could you perhaps at least comment your code? Five nested scopes is maybe too much?

Comment: The line `int A[T][20000];` which allocates up to 1.6 megabytes (`20*20000*sizeof(int)`) on the stack looks very dangerous. You may want to consider using the heap instead, by using dynamic memory allocation (e.g. `malloc`).

Comment: Also note that the ISO C11 standard does not require that [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are supported. This means that your code may not run on some platforms.

Comment: You might want to take a look at hashmaps

Comment: You can cut down on the storage by interleaving the input and output for each test case, i.e. do not read the input for test case #2 until you have printed the output for test case #1.

Comment: Very confusing question, in this case frequency = number of occurences. Anyway the bubble sort at the start is O(n^2) and could be optimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a couple of days but i finally got how to do this. Apparently, it was not as complicated as i thought... here is the working code. Thanks to everyone who helped :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int T, N;
    
    scanf("%d", &T);
    
    for (int i = 0; i<T; i++) {
        
        scanf("%d", &N); getchar();
        
        //INPUT elements and counting frequncy for each element
        int f[200001] = {0}, E = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j<N; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &E); getchar();
            f[E]++;
        }
        
        //find max frequency and how many elements with max frequency
        int max = 0, c = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j<200001; j++) {
            
            if (f[j] == max) {
                c ++;
            }
            
            if (f[j]>max) {
                max = f[j];
                c = 1;
            }
            
        }
        
        //OUTPUT result
        printf("Case #%d: %d\n", i+1, max);
        int counter = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j<200001; j++) {
            if (f[j] == max) {
                
                counter ++;
                if (counter<c){
                    printf("%d ", j);   
                } else {
                    printf("%d\n", j);
                }
                
            } 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```